# why dbreport response 202 accepted,I need 200

Tags: oracle, response

*
This API used to insert DB.
When I request for this ESB API response 202 accepted,but I need 200 
I didn't set asynchronous request.Please excuse my poor English.Do I make myself clear?Thanks.
*

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="xxxxxx" context="/xxxxxxx">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/xxxxxx">
      <inSequence>
            <property name="requestMsg" expression="json-eval($)"/>
            <property name="children" expression="json-eval($.children)"/>
           <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property> 
         <dbreport>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxx:1521/xxxxxx</url>
                  <user>xxxxxx</user>
                  <password>xxxxxx</password>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>INSERT INTO TABLE (CARDID )VALUES(?)</sql>
               <parameter expression="//CARDID/text()" type="CHAR"/>
            </statement>
         </dbreport> 
         <foreach id="foreach_1" expression="//children">
            <sequence>
                  <property name="PKID" expression="json-eval($.children.PKID)"/>
               <dbreport>
                  <connection>
                     <pool>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx</url>
                        <user>xxxxxx</user>
                        <password>xxxxxx</password>
                     </pool>
                  </connection>
                  <statement>
                     <sql>INSERT INTO TABLE_1 ( PKID )VALUES  ( ? )</sql>
                     <parameter expression="//PKID/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
                  </statement>
               </dbreport>
            </sequence>
         </foreach>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some tags to your question to provide some content. I added "oracle" for you since I think it might maybe be about oracle-db. Maybe visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: To add a more content-related comment: 202 seems to be the correct response code for that kind of action. Why do you need 200? Maybe the problem is more on the client side expecting exactly 200 and not any 2xx code to assume success.